# Does the GDAL GeoJSON driver read or write multipart geometries?

Tags: python, gdal, geometry, ogr, multipart

In the [documentation for the GDAL GeoJSON driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html), I can only see mention of primitive geometries.  Does the GDAL GeoJSON driver read [multipart geometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) like MultiLineString?  If not, is there another established GeoJSON driver with a python interface that can read multipart GeoJSON type geometries from a URL?

Answer (score 2):

GDAL has no problem with GeoJSON http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html. The following GeoJSON encodes one multilinestring:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[11.20558631,46.48251782],[11.2058444,46.48280049]],[[11.20578705,46.48252192],[11.20596731,46.48275133]]],"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}} }
]

}
```

Save as multiline.json and test with ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo multiline.json -al
INFO: Open of `multiline.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.

Layer name: OGRGeoJSON
Geometry: Multi Line String
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (11.205586, 46.482518) - (11.205967, 46.482800)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
OGRFeature(OGRGeoJSON):0
  MULTILINESTRING ((11.20558631 46.48251782,11.2058444 46.48280049),(11.20578705
 46.48252192,11.20596731 46.48275133))
```

GDAL probably has problems with the ESRI style JSON that is also handled with the same GDAL driver than GeoJSON http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html.